# Use LUA script with SCAN command to obtain the list?

Tags: lua, redis

I would like to use the SCAN command to query the list by MATCH and count parameters, since I'm new to redis and lua, how could I wrote such script ?
Below script is right ?

```
local cursor = "0";
local list = {};
repeat
    local result = redis.call("SCAN", cursor, "MATCH", KEYS[1], "COUNT", 10);
    cursor = result[1];
    list += result[2]; **// How can I appened the list ?**
    end;
    cursor = t[1];
until cursor == "0";
return list;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The script looks ok from a cursory scan. I assume that you're asking how to concatenate tables in Lua. From what I know, up to Lua 5.1, the way to do that is a simple loop:

```
for _, v in ipairs(result[2]) do
  list[#list+1] = v
end
```